# Apache PDFBox 2.0.18 - Comments/Annotations status linking

Tags: java, annotations, comments, pdfbox

I need to merge comments taken from many versions of the same pdf file but with different comments, into one PDF file containing all comments.

I take all the comments from the pages and create an arrayList of them, then I simply set this array of comments on the new pdf file and it works pretty well.

The problem is that I also need to create an Excel with all the comments found and together with their "status" (accepted, cancelled, rejected, ecc...).

The status seems to be managed as a separate annotation/comment from PDFBox and I can't find any relation between a comment and its status.

Example:

I have a **PDAnnotation object** with content "COMMENT 1".

And I have another **PDAnnotation object** with content "Accepted by user XX" (the status of COMMENT 1).

On Acrobat Reader I see the comment "COMMENT 1" with the status set on "Accepted", so there must be a relation between the two objects, but I can't find it.

Any ideas?

Comment: please share such files, and/or look at the annotations with PDFDebugger, maybe this can give a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the PDFDebugger is a good suggestion, it should give to you an overview of how objects (including PDAnnotations) are linked to each other

Anyway, check if in your child PDAnnotation in the `COSDictionary` you have a `COSBase{IRT}` key, that key should contain as value the parent `COSObject`

So if you do something link this:

`COSDictionary parentDict = (COSDictionary) childDict.getDictionaryObject("IRT");`

You should get the parent PDAnnotation dictionary and you can take all the data you need

Please notice the cast is necessary since `getDictionaryObject` returns a `COSBase`, but the object returned for the IRT key is actually a `COSDictionary`